# Does anyone recognize this modulation?

Tags: frequency, modulation, demodulation, time-frequency, software-defined-radio

I'm trying to extract the code of my garage remote, but i have some difficulty to find witch modulation has been used.
At first I thought it was a simple digital modulation, but there is some strange situation that it seems that the signal changes phase.
Here are some pieces of signal extracted with my SDR dongle:
f.Carrier = 868.25Mhz
T.rectangle = 400us
[image]
[image]

Here is the spectrum of the signal:
[image]
[image]

Comment: What are the red and blue lines?

Comment: Are we looking at time vs. amplitude?

Comment: @MBaz The blue line it's the real signal and extracted and the reds rectangles are a 400us reference used for divide the signal over time and to help me understand

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Yes exactly

Comment: Well, if it's the phase that's odd, then you should probably include that information as well. What about the spectrum?

Comment: If that spectrum was obtained using I&Q (vs just I), then this looks like plain old 2-FSK.  On a waterfall display with a high enough update rate, you might be able to see the signal alternating between the frequency two bins.

Comment: BOC(1,1),maybe?